# Thunderbird character-encoding problem

Tags: thunderbird, character-encoding

In folder properties, if I choose iso-8859-9 or windows-1254, messages with utf-8 headers does not show Turkish characters correct and if I choose utf-8, messages with iso-8859-9 and windows-1254 does not show Turkish characters correct. How can I overcome this problem?